# WPF ListViewItem Trigger Background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following simple window:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView BorderThickness="0">

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListViewItem Content="Just a test"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="Another test"/>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So when the item is selected the background should become red and the border thickness should become "0". The thickness works but the background color does not work. Any idea what I did wrong here? It seems all brush related properties can not be applied (e.g. BorderBrush does also not work)

Answer (score 0):

The default template for the ListViewItem is not set up to look at the Background property for the color of the item when its selected.

Its set up to look for a solid color brush with a key of "Item.SelectedActive.Background"

To check how the default style template is set up, right click on one of the items in your list in the designer, select Edit Template > Edit a Copy:[image: Screenshot1]

It will add some code to the top of your Window xaml under <Window.Resources>

You'll want to pay particularly close attention to the selected text below:
[image: generated style]

This is what controls the background color of the selected item.  You can simply change the Color value to Red or whatever color you want for the highlighted color and you're off to the races.

You could create your own template but the built in one is pretty robust already.